# Long running callback with Angular's $q

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm a complete novice when it comes to AngularJS although I'm trying to learn as quickly as possible. Something I cannot get my head around is if a function needs to have a long running callback.

I'm using the Ionic framework to create a Cordova phone app. One particular library that I'm using through the ngCordova module has a `connect` method. On a successful bluetooth connection the `successCallback` is called. On an unsuccessful connection the `errorCallback` is called. This is expected behaviour. However, this particular method *should* call the `errorCallback` should a disconnect happen at any point. However, the promise has already been resolved through the `successCallback`.

I did look into using the `notifyCallback` option however this cannot be used if the promise is fulfilled.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation of the function(s) that, if I understand correctly, you're trying to wrap into a promise?

Comment: It's a bit long-winded due to it being a Cordova plugin but essentially:

Phone side: [Line 256](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/blob/master/src/ios/MEGBluetoothSerial.m)
JS side: [Line 4](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/blob/master/www/bluetoothSerial.js)


The callback assigned to the `connect` function is called on a successful connect. If, after connecting, the device is disconnected then the failure callback from the `connect` function is called.

Comment: To me, you need two promises: The first one is resolved on successful connection, and rejected if the connection fails. The second one is only created after the first one is resolved, and is resolved (or rejected) once the connection is lost. The result returned by the first promise should thus have the second promise as one of its fields.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand you. This is the code:     `connect: function (address) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        $window.bluetoothSerial.connect(address, function () {
          q.resolve();
        }, function (error) {
          q.reject(error);
        });
        return q.promise;
      }`

Presumably after the `q.resolve()` I need to have another promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't realise was the error callback would be called even after the original promise had been resolved. The only difference was that the reject wasn't ever processed as the promise was fulfilled.

The original code was:

```
  connect: function (address) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    $window.bluetoothSerial.connect(address, function () {
      q.resolve();
    }, function (error) {
      q.reject(error);
    });
    return q.promise;
  }
```

The updated code is now:

```
  connect: function (address) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var disconnectionPromise = $q.defer();
    var isConnected = false;
    $window.bluetoothSerial.connect(address, function () {
      isConnected = true;
      q.resolve(disconnectionPromise);
    }, function (error) {
      if(isConnected === true) {
      disconnectionPromise.reject(error);
      }
      q.reject(error);
    });
    return q.promise;
  }
```

The usage is as in [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502716/long-running-callback-with-angulars-q/29503665#29503665)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation of the function I would implement to be able to use promises with this API. I'll leave the implementation as an exercise:

```
/**
 * Tries connecting using bluetooth. Returns a promise. 
 * If the connection doesn't succeed, the returned promise is rejected.
 * If the connection succeeds, the returned promise is resolved with
 * an other promise (that we will call disconnectionPromise). 
 * This disconnectionPromise is never resolved.
 * It's rejected once the connection (which has been 
 * successfully established) fails. 
 */
function connect() {
    ...
}
```

So, an example usage would be:

```
var blueToothConnection = service.connect();
blueToothConnection.then(function(disconnectionPromise) {
    console.log("connection successfully established");
    disconnectionPromise.catch(function() {
        console.log("connection lost");
    });
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("impossible to establish a connection");
});
```

Comment: I don't think that works. I'm trying to get my head around it all however the system actually runs as follows:

1) Tries to connect. If successful then promise is resolved. If unsuccessful promise is rejected.
2) If connection is disconnected then the errorCallback is called.

I can't see a way to make that happen because you can't link the callback from the original call once it has been resolved?

Comment: The error callback should reject the first promise if it hasn't been resolved yet (use a boolean flag to know). If the first promise has already been resolved, it should reject the second promise.

Comment: I'm completely confused now. The error callback won't be called if the connection has been made because the promise will have already been resolved, or is that incorrect?

Comment: You got it in your answer. Congrats. Except it should be `q.resolve(disconnectionPromise.promise);`

Comment: That's what I originally tried, but it didn't work for some reason. I'm trying to debug to work out why.